# How can I get easier enemies in casual mode?

Tags: hearthstone

The daily quests often force me to play some classes that I have not much experience with and no good decks for. This makes it rather frustrating to play them when the matchmaking puts me against opponents that would be fair for my best class and deck.

One idea would be to repeatedly concede every casual game directly at the beginning to lower my win rate and get ranked lower in the matchmaking. But that seems like a rather obvious tactic and I would guess that Blizzard might have done something to prevent players from exploiting this.

Does repeatedly conceding to lower your own rank in casual play work? Are there any other ways to get yourself to rank yourself lower to make it easier to fulfill daily quests?

Comment: You don't need to concede. With the state of the servers at the moment you just need to play and watch the disconnections kill your ranking.

Comment: if you don't care about your rank, tank back down to 20 and its very easy to win games with any deck at that level.

Comment: Once a day you can drop a quest that you don't want, and the game will give you a replacement. There's always a chance that the replacement will be better suited to what you're good at.

Answer (score 2):

No reason to concede before you draw, you might get a lucky break, but people should concede more often.

Just play a few turns and see how it's going.

If someone has you at 1 health with a full board and you have no minions, you wouldn't feel obliged to play it out, right?

If your draw is awful and they have great board presence after a turn or two, maybe no need to play out every excruciating turn there either.

There is a middle ground between conceding instantly and holding out hope until the very last moment of every game.

Some games swing back and forth, sure, but if you're trying to win as many games as possible in a limited amount of time, the key is to develop a sense of which games are worth playing for wins, and which games are best ended as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes repeatedly conceding does lower your rank, after you lowered up your rank to the bottom, you will face bots which stay afk until the last second of their turn. Their tactic is to get you pissed of and concede or hope for you to disconnect. This way they farm 3 win quests.

I haven't heard of and can't imagine other ways to lower your rank, unless using a bot like this.

But instead of this I recommend you to either drop your quests or only play with your good decks in ranked game and quest decks in normal game.

Comment: Don't those bots just end up facing other such bots?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that the matchmaking in the Casual Bracket does work with sort of a personal match making rating (MMR). That rating works similarly to the comparable ratings in other Blizzard games: the more you win (especially against people with a higher MMR than you) will add MMR points, the more you loose (especially against people with a lower MMR than you) will subtract MMR points. So loosing a lot of games allows you to loose some MMR rating and face easier opponents. You facing a lot of decks you cannot seem to beat would mean that your MMR is to high for your current deck collection (meaning you have to have played some pretty good games before).

Always remember though: you can also complete quests in the arena. If your gold count permits, this is always an alternative. Otherwise ranked play (as long as you are in the lower leagues) serves the same purpose, since you are almost always matched against someone within your league vicinity and not necessarily MMR.

Hope this helped. :-)